# In python, what's the most efficient way to identify clusters of n-events t-time apart?

Tags: python

For example, if I have the following event data, and want to find clusters of at least 2 events that are within 1 minute of each other in which id_1, id_2, and id_3 are all the same. For reference, I have the epoch timestamp (in microseconds) in addition to the date-time timestamp.

```
event_id       timestamp          id_1 id_2  id_3
9442823 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   1   34567
9442821 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   2   12345
9442817 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   3   34567
9442814 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   1   12345
9442813 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   2   34567
9442810 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   3   12345
9442805 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   1   34567
9442876 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   A   2   12345
9442866 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   A   3   34567
9442858 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   A   1   12345
9442845 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   C   2   34567
9442840 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   C   3   12345
9442839 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   C   1   34567
9442838 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   C   2   12345
9442907 Jun 15, 2015 10:24 PM PDT   C   3   34567
9442886 Jun 15, 2015 10:24 PM PDT   C   1   12345
9442949 Jun 15, 2015 10:25 PM PDT   C   2   34567
9442934 Jun 15, 2015 10:25 PM PDT   C   3   12345
```

For each cluster found, I want to return a set of (id_1, id_2, id_3, [list of event_ids], min_timestamp_of_cluster, max_timestamp_of_cluster). Additionally, if there's a cluster with (e.g.) 6 events, I'd only want to return a single result with all events, not one for each grouping of 3 events.

Comment: So, this is a csv, presumably?

Comment: Data is currently in a pandas DataFrame, but I'm not tied to this being the data format.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can make use of scikit-learn's DBSCAN clustering algorithm with a custom distance (or metric) function. Your distance function should return a very large number if either of the id_1, id_2 or id_3's are different. Otherwise is should return the time difference.

But with this method, the number of clusters are determined by the algorithm and not as an input given to the algorithm. If you are determined to pass the number of clusters as an input, k-means is the clustering algorithm you may need to look into.

Answer (score 0):

In pure python, use a "sliding window" that encompasses all the events in a 1 minute range.

The premise is simple: maintain a queue of events that is a subsequence
of the total list, in order. The "window" (queue) should be all the events you care about. In this case, that is determined by the 60-second time gap requirement.

As you process events, add one event to the end of the queue. If the first event in the queue is more than 60 seconds from the newly-added last event, slide the window forward by dropping the first event from the front of the queue.

This is python3:

```
import collections
import operator
import itertools

from datetime import datetime

#### FROM HERE: vvv is just faking events. Delete or replace.

class Event(collections.namedtuple('Event', 'event_id timestamp id_1 id_2 id_3 epoch_ts')):
    def __str__(self):
        return ('{e.event_id} {e.timestamp}  {e.id_1}  {e.id_2}  {e.id_3}'
                .format(e=self))

def get_events():
    event_list = map(operator.methodcaller('strip'), '''
        9442823 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   1   34567
        9442821 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   2   12345
        9442817 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   3   34567
        9442814 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   1   12345
        9442813 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   2   34567
        9442810 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   3   12345
        9442805 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT   A   1   34567
        9442876 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   A   2   12345
        9442866 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   A   3   34567
        9442858 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   A   1   12345
        9442845 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   C   2   34567
        9442840 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   C   3   12345
        9442839 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   C   1   34567
        9442838 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT   C   2   12345
        9442907 Jun 15, 2015 10:24 PM PDT   C   3   34567
        9442886 Jun 15, 2015 10:24 PM PDT   C   1   12345
        9442949 Jun 15, 2015 10:25 PM PDT   C   2   34567
        9442934 Jun 15, 2015 10:25 PM PDT   C   3   12345
    '''.strip().splitlines())

    for line in event_list:
        idev, *rest = line.split()
        ts = rest[:6]
        id1, id2, id3 = rest[6:]
        id2 = int(id2)  # faster when sorting (see find_clustered_events)
        id3 = int(id3)  # faster when sorting (see find_clustered_events)
        ts_str = ' '.join(ts)
        dt = datetime.strptime(ts_str.replace('PDT', '-0700'), '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p %z')
        epoch = dt.timestamp()
        ev = Event(idev, ts_str, id1, id2, id3, epoch)
        yield ev

#### TO HERE: ^^^  was just faking up your events. Delete or replace.


def add_cluster(key, group):
    '''Do whatever you want with the clusters. I'll print them.'''

    print('Cluster:', key)
    print('    ','\n    '.join(map(str, group)), sep='')


def find_clustered_events(events, cluster=3, gap_secs=60):
    '''Call add_cluster on clusters of events within a maximum time gap.

    Args:
        events (iterable): series of events, in chronological order
        cluster (int): minimum number of events in a cluster
        gap_secs (float): maximum time-gap from start to end of cluster

    Returns:
        None.

    '''
    window = collections.deque()
    evkey = lambda e: (e.id_1, e.id_2, e.id_3)

    for ev in events:
        window.append(ev)

        t0 = window[0].epoch_ts
        tn = window[-1].epoch_ts

        if tn - t0 < gap_secs:
            continue

        window.pop()

        for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(window, key=evkey), key=evkey):
            group = tuple(g)
            if len(group) >= cluster:
                add_cluster(k, group)

        window.append(ev)
        window.popleft()

# Call find_clustered with event generator, cluster args. 
# Note that your data doesn't have any 3-clusters without time seconds. :-(

find_clustered_events(get_events(), cluster=2)
```

The output looks like this:

```
$ python test.py
Cluster: ('A', 1, 34567)
    9442823 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT  A  1  34567
    9442805 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT  A  1  34567
Cluster: ('A', 2, 12345)
    9442821 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT  A  2  12345
    9442876 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT  A  2  12345
Cluster: ('A', 3, 34567)
    9442817 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT  A  3  34567
    9442866 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT  A  3  34567
Cluster: ('A', 1, 12345)
    9442814 Jun 15, 2015 10:22 PM PDT  A  1  12345
    9442858 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT  A  1  12345
Cluster: ('C', 2, 34567)
    9442845 Jun 15, 2015 10:23 PM PDT  C  2  34567
    9442949 Jun 15, 2015 10:25 PM PDT  C  2  34567
```

Please note: the code above doesn't try to keep track of events already in a cluster. So if you have, for example, an event type that occurs every fifteen seconds, you will have a sequence like this:

```
 event1   t=0:00
 event2   t=0:15
 event3   t=0:30
 event4   t=0:45
 event5   t=1:00
```

And you will get overlapping clusters:

```
event1, event2, event3 (t=0:00 .. 0:30)
event2, event3, event4 (t=0:15 .. 0:45)
event3, event4, event5 (t=0:30 .. 1:00)
```

Technically, those are valid clusters, each slightly different. But you may wish to expunge previously-clustered events from the window, if you want the events to only appear in a single cluster.

Alternatively, if the chance of clustering and repetition is low, it might improve performance to implement repeat-checking in the `add_cluster()` function, to reduce the work done by the main loop.

A final note: this does a *LOT* of sorting. And the sorting is not efficient, since it gets repeated every time a new event appears. If you have a large data set, the performance will probably be bad. If your event keys are relatively few - that is, if the id1,2,3 values tend to repeat over and over again - you would be better off dynamically creating separate deques for each distinct key (id1+id2+id3) and dispatching the event to the appropriate deque, applying the same window logic, and then checking the length of the deque.

On the other hand, if you are processing something like web-server logs, where the requester is always changing, that might tend to create a memory problem with all the useless deques. So this is a memory vs. time trade-off you'll have to be aware of.